# Flutter JSON использование переменных

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Я новичок во флатере и дарте, потихоньку изучаю.
Сейчас встал вопрос получения данных из JSON. Я написал небольшой код для получения данных Json для верификации пользователя (возвращает значение result). Также в этом запросе имееются значения name и userID. Как мне их использовать в других окнах, виджетах (типа Text), для новых json запросов и т.д. как переменные?

JSON:

```
{
  "result": {
    "Result": 0,
    "RequiredInfo": 0,
    "Custom": {},
    "Name": "1",
    "UserId": 4,
    "AuthenticationType": "",
    "Role": 1,
    "Claims": [
      {
        "type": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name",
        "value": "1"
      }
    ]
  },
  "httpStatusCode": 200
}
```

Вот мой код для получения данных по нажатию кнопки:

```
      final loginUser = loginUserText.text;
      final passUser = passwordUserText.text;
      final url = Uri.parse(
          'http://ХХХ.ХХ.ХХХ.ХХХ/api/users/$loginUser/$passUser/valid');
      final response = await http
          .get(url, headers: <String, String>{'authorization': basicAuth});
      Map<String, dynamic> parsed = json.decode(response.body);
      final user = User.fromJson(parsed);

      if (user.httpStatusCode == 200 && user.result!.result == 0) {
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/main_screen');
      } else {
        _showMyDialog();
      }
    }
```

Comment: В оф. документации весьма хорошо объясняется это... [читаем](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro) и [выбираем](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options).

Comment: Советую сначала попробовать `Provider`, перед выбором. Даже при том что это не всегда удобный подход, лично мне он помог лучше понять некоторые общие принципы (такие как инъекция объектных зависимостей), и более осознанно сделать выбор. Тем более что с простыми приложениями, этот рекомендуемый подход вполне удобен - тем что простой, и предполагает не так много бойлерплейтов. То что с ним границы модели и контроллера слегка размыты, поначалу работает только в плюс (меньше сущностей, меньше головной боли). Перекатиться на что-то другое позже, это в принципе не такая уж проблема.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий. Не подскажите, есть ли способ вытащить значение user.result!.userId из этой функции?

Comment: Да, есть множество способов для множества разных ситуаций. Если функция вызывается в процедурном коде, то проще всего будет возвратить (см. оператор `return`) это значение из функции, ну и соотв. принимать его как резолв возвращаемого объекта `Future`.